# unity not recognising a collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

[image]

```
2 snippets of code from 2 separate scripts
    protected virtual void OnCollide(Collider2D coll)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnCollide was not implemented in" + this.name);
    }
}



    protected override void OnCollide(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.tag == "Fighter")
        {
            if (coll.name != "Player")
            {
                Debug.Log(coll.name);

            }
        
        }
    }
private void Swing()
{
    Debug.Log("Swing");
}
```

}

running into a problem that when I collide with an enemy (there is meant to be a console notification) nothing happens, no errors appear, I cant seem to find any problems with my code, the collision is registered with my test npc but not the enemy

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `OnCollisionEnter` instead of `OnCollide`?

Comment: OnCollide isn’t the right method name. OnCollisionEnter2D is what Youre after

Comment: Unity Collision Conditions and Trigger Conditions:
1. At least one of the two objects has a rigid body
2. The trigger needs to check the Trigger property in the Collider component
3. Both the collision and the collided objects need to be added with the Collider collision component

Answer (score 0):

As BugFinder and sorold both said, you named the method wrong. It is supposed to be `OnCollisinEnter` or `OnCollisionEnter2D` based on which version you use.

Unity checks if you have specific methods in your script. If you do not, they won't call that method, but if Unity recognizes that method name, it will be called.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but when i added a rigidbody to it or to that colliding object, it fixed.